# Push Notification from Pusher/Beams won't show up in emulator

Tags: python, android-studio, push-notification, pusher

I set up a Pusher/Beams account for my android app but when I execute the script to send a notification it doesn't show up on the android studios emulator running my app.
Android Studios code:

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.pusher.pushnotifications.PushNotifications;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PushNotifications.start(getApplicationContext(), "instance_id");
        PushNotifications.subscribe("hello");
    }
}
```

Python script to send notification:
    from pusher_push_notifications import PushNotifications

```
pn_client = PushNotifications(
    instance_id='INSTANCE_ID',
    secret_key='SECRET_KEY')

def notify(title, message, data):
    response = pn_client.publish(
      interests=['hello'],
      publish_body={
        'fcm': {
            'notification': {
                'title': title, 
                'body': message
                }}})

    print(response['publishId'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your app is minimized. Your publish payload is UI-only, so it will only show up in the system tray if your app is minimized.

Comment: Ok I see it showing up as the app icon in the top bar. But I need it to show up as a heads-up notification. Is there anyway to do that through Beams. I can't find any documentation for that aspect